# unknown type name __locale_ ( while building gcc for powerpc)

Tags: gcc, powerpc

I am trying to build gcc 4.3-74 for powerpc using cross compilation. I used the following configure command to configure the make file.

> ./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu --target=powerpc-linux
>   --host=powerpc-linux --with-gmp=/xxx/include --with-gmp-include=/xxx/include --with-gmp-lib=/xxx/lib

configuration is done successfully, but when I do a make, it failed with the following message

```
In file included from ../.././libiberty/floatformat.c:31:0:
/usr/include/string.h:548:5: error: unknown type name â€˜__locale_tâ€™
     __locale_t __loc)
     ^
/usr/include/string.h:552:18: error: unknown type name â€˜__locale_tâ€™
```

It seems like it is not fetching the right header file for powerpc.

I had similar issue with building binutils when I did configure without option --host=powerpc-linux. As soon as I used an option --host=powerpc-linux in configure, the same error is gone in case of binutils.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was using some pretty old compiler for compilation. This old compiler was set to PATH variable in my user profile. Hence when I was executing gcc, it was executing old one and it resulted in this error.

I removed PATH setting in my user profile. Now when I run gcc, it is executing the latest gcc. The problem is solved now.

Comment: I am using GCC 4.8 and still have the same problem as mentioned by OP.